# Get row before the negative value in certain column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to get who row data **just before the negative value** of column X1.

For example, if the dataframe has two column data...

```
X1   X2
3    1
5    2
-3   4
1    6
3    7
5    4
-4   9
```

The expected out come should be

```
5   2  #row before -3
5   4  #row before -4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to search for negative values only in `X1` column we can do

```
df[which(df$X1 < 0) - 1, ]

#  X1 X2
#2  5  2
#6  5  4
```